# I'm getting a weird error for a program that seems like it should "just work."

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, 2d

I present to you all a program I'm working on for my college programming course. I still have a little ways to go before it completely meets my assignment's requirements, but I've gotten a basic draft of the program error-free (supposedly) and it appears to run… but then it suddenly kicks me into Xcode's debugger and gives me:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2, address=0x7fff95c1e5f5)
```

Here's the command line output, up until it kicks me out:

```
    -----------------------
    Quarterly_sales_taxator
    -----------------------


    How many company divisions will we be dealing with?  2


    Am I correct in assuming that there are 4 sales quarters?    yes



    Please enter the sales Company Division #1 brought in for Sales Quarter #1   20
    (lldb)
```

Here's my code:

```
    //
    //  quarterly_sales_taxator.cpp
    //  Ch. 7 program #7
    //
    //  Created by John Doe on 11/27/12.
    //

    #include <iostream>
    #include <iomanip>
    #include <string>
    #include <sstream>
    #include <cctype>
    using namespace std;

    void read_company_divisions_and_sales_quarters(double **, int, int);
        //void write_company_divisions_and_sales_quarters_to_array(double **, int, int);    // This will be used later on to read data from a file.
    void display_quarterly_sales_array(double **, int, int);

    string temp;    // A global temporary placeholder variable; I use this several times.


    int main()
    {
        int COMPANY_DIVISIONS,
            SALES_QUARTERS = 4;

        double **quarterly_sales_form;


        cout << "\n\n-----------------------\nQuarterly_sales_taxator\n-----------------------\n\n";

        cout << "\nHow many company divisions will we be dealing with?  ";
        getline(cin, temp);
        stringstream(temp)>>COMPANY_DIVISIONS;

        while (COMPANY_DIVISIONS < 1 || isdigit(COMPANY_DIVISIONS == false))
        {
            cout << "\n\n------"
                 << "\nError:"
                 << "\n------"
                 << "\n\nYou have entered an invalid choice."
                 << "\nPlease type a number greater than zero.    ";

            getline(cin, temp);
            stringstream(temp)>>COMPANY_DIVISIONS;
        }

        cout << "\n\nAm I correct in assuming that there are 4 sales quarters?    ";
        getline(cin, temp);

                // Convert to uppercase.
            for (int count = 0; count < temp.length(); count ++)
            {
                temp[count] = toupper(temp[count]);
            }

            if (temp == "NO" || temp == "NOPE" || temp == "INCORRECT" || temp == "YOU ARE NOT" || temp == "YOU ARE INCORRECT" || temp == "NEGATIVE" || temp == "NEGATORY")
            {
                cout << "\nOk, then how many sales quarters are we dealing with?    ";
                getline(cin, temp);
                stringstream(temp)>>SALES_QUARTERS;
            }

        cout << endl << endl;

            // This sets up the 2d array.
        quarterly_sales_form = new double *[COMPANY_DIVISIONS];
        for (int count = 0; count < COMPANY_DIVISIONS; count ++)
        {   quarterly_sales_form[COMPANY_DIVISIONS] = new double [SALES_QUARTERS];  }

        read_company_divisions_and_sales_quarters(quarterly_sales_form, COMPANY_DIVISIONS, SALES_QUARTERS);
            //  write_company_divisions_and_sales_quarters_to_array(quarterly_sales_form, COMPANY_DIVISIONS, SALES_QUARTERS);   // I'll add this feature later.


        cout << "\n\nHere's what you entered:\n\n";
        display_quarterly_sales_array(quarterly_sales_form, COMPANY_DIVISIONS, SALES_QUARTERS);

            // Since we used a series of pointers, we need to free the allocated space back up.
        for (int count = 0; count < COMPANY_DIVISIONS; count ++)
        {   delete[] quarterly_sales_form[COMPANY_DIVISIONS];  }
        delete[] quarterly_sales_form;



        return 0;
    }


    /*############################################
     # read_company_divisions_and_sales_quarters #
     ############################################*/
    void read_company_divisions_and_sales_quarters(double **array, int DIVISIONS, int QUARTERS)
    {

            for (int count = 0; count < QUARTERS; count++)
            {

                for (int index = 0; index < DIVISIONS; index++)
                {
                    cout << "\nPlease enter the sales Company Division #" << count+1 << " brought in for Sales Quarter #" << index+1 << "   ";
                    getline(cin, temp);
                    stringstream(temp) >> array[count][index];
                }
            }
    }


    /*################################
     # display_quarterly_sales_array #
     #################################*/
    void display_quarterly_sales_array(double **array, int DIVISIONS, int QUARTERS)
    {
        for (int count = 0; count < DIVISIONS; count++)
        {
            cout << "\nCompany division #" << count+1 << ":\n";
            for (int index = 0; index < QUARTERS; index++)
            {    cout << array[count][index] << ", ";    }
        }

    }
```

Can some kind soul please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What line of code does the debugger say caused the problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This expression : `isdigit(COMPANY_DIVISIONS == false)` does not do what you think it does.

Comment: Rob, I would normally agree with you, but for some reason it doesn't seem to work the way it should on in compiler I've used over the last few weeks. I don't understand why, but "!isdigit(variable)" hasn't worked for 2 months for me, on any machine I've used

Comment: Perhaps because you've been calling it on an `int`? `isdigit` takes a `char` and tells you whether that character represents one of the digits. It doesn't make sense to call it on an integer.

Comment: You're absolutely right, and the only reason it's called on an integer right now is that I've skipped several input validation checks that will be necessary only once the program is complete, so I pasted in the string stream as a quick reference point for later editing. The string itself will ultimately be checked, rather than an int

Comment: It's dirty, and I've made several similar mistakes in this code, so I guess I need to get some sleep more often...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    {   quarterly_sales_form[COMPANY_DIVISIONS] = new double [SALES_QUARTERS];  }
```

In this line, `COMPANY_DIVISIONS` should be `count`.

Comment: and at another place (when `delete`ing the elements) too.

Comment: That's one bug, but there's a few others, some of which were mentioned by Dietmar Kühl; the code is also looping on the wrong variable(s).

Comment: Wow… I'm speechless… It's obviously been far too long a day… Many thanks, sir!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what Dan Hulme said, it seems this line

```
stringstream(temp) >> array[count][index];
```

should really be

```
std::istringstream(temp) >> std::skipws >> array[index][count];
```

In addition to using `std::istringstream` rather than `std::stringstream` and making sure that an lvalue is at hand, which isn't strictly needed until the type read becomes more interesting, this also reverses the indices: `index` runs over `COMPANY_DIVISIONS` and `count` over `SALES_QUARTERS`.

The real question is, of course: Who hands out assignments like this? Pointer manipulations and allocations are best left to low-level library writers. This is C++ not C: we can and should use abstractions. Getting this code exception safe is a major challenge and there is no point in teaching people how to write broken (e.g. exception unsafe) code.

Comment: Not just that, but the whole prompt thing looks like an example from an 80's BASIC textbook. User interaction just doesn't work this way any more.

Comment: But, why would I use the std:: prefix when I've already #included the library?

Comment: Please don't misunderstand my reason for asking: I genuinely wish to learn from my mistakes and make advancement, I'm making no attempt to be confrontational.

Comment: Including a header has nothing to do with the namespace qualification: The include just makes declarations available, hopefully in a namespace. To avoid the qualification you'd use something like `using namespace std;` (a `using` directive). I prefer explicit qualification because it clearly indicates where a name comes from which is especially important when there are many potential namespaces.

Comment: I agree with @DietmarKühl. Using `std::` where you need it instead of blatting `using namespace std;` at the top of your program is especially important for beginners, to remind you which names are from your program and which are from the standard library.

Comment: Ah, I think I get it. Thank you, both!